# Python time does not match the correct format

Tags: python

I have the following string:

> 2016-04-29T00:00:00+01:00

I want to turn it into a Unix date timestamp using Python.

I've tried this to convert it into a date object:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(validated_data.get('scheduled_datetime', None), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

But I get the following error:

```
time data '2016-04-29T00:00:00+01:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: @user3159253 Typo, should be ``%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
2016-04-29T00:00:00+01:00
```

is not in a form that [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) can understand. It supports

> `%z` UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM

but note that there is no colon `:` in the timezone!

So first remove the colon `:` from your input and then use `%z`.

Comment: ``unconverted data remains: +01:00`` using ``%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S``

Comment: Yes, you must first change your *input*  so that `strptime` can understand it. Either remove the timezone (`date[:-6]`) or remove the last `:`.

Comment: I see, I found it understands when I do this ``parse_datetime(validated_data.get('scheduled_datetime', None))`` using ``django.utils.dateparse`` thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the current date in a specific format, you should use time.strftime().

```
import time
currentDate = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dTT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

No need to over complicate things with datetime.

Note: You may need to change some of the formatting characters in order to get the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt strptime supports %z in python 2.7. Either you can upgrade to python 3 version or use parser module

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse(time_str)
    datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```